# Grouping Excel graph categories

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to group categories in an Excel graph or provide color distinctions? I have searched around and while their are ways to group categories in 2D graphs, I have not found an example the uses a z-axis. In the example below, the desired group separation is shown in the red, orange, and turquoise polygon's. If there is not a way to separate the groups to provide distinction, is there a way to change the bar colors to provide category group separate designations?

[image]

**Conclusion:**

If you only have a single series of data, you may "Vary colors by point" per http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vary-the-colors-of-same-series-data-markers-in-a-chart-HP010007429.aspx#BM2. This does not work if you have a graph with more than one series whether 3D or not.

The option I have found is to double-click each data-point (in this case bar) and manually change the color.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to create 3 different series of data.

Sample (not yours but enough to hopefully get you started)

```
column    A    B    C
Data 1    1
Data 2    2
Data 3    3
Data 4         2
Data 5         3
Data 6         4
Data 7              3
Data 8              4
Data 9              5
```

Now you can color the series' different colors, and not have to color each individual point.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best not to overcomplicate things with too many colors, though shades of colors might work.

However, the first thing to do is to make a 2D chart. The 3D chart is useless for comparing the sizes of bars, and while you have data labels on all the bars, it's not as useful as a table, because a table lines up the values in an easier to read arrangement.

[image: Clustered Column Chart]

By inserting blank rows between blocks of data, you can effectively cluster groups of columns together in the chart.

[image: Clustered Clustered Column Chart]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this:*

**:Caveat:**

- *The post by @guitarthrower inspired me to find the solution.*
- The source data must be divided into groups, as I did in range
  `E37:H46`.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell F37:

  `=IF(ISBLANK($E38),NA(),IF($B38=F$37,$C38,NA()))`
- Select *E37:H46* and hit draw *Clustered Column Chart*.
- Using **C**lustered Column Chart automatically avoids #NA error from the
  Chart.
- Select Color combination & assign *Series Overlap* & *Gap Width* as
  required.